# Stuck with following error when Installing Json.NET for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, json.net, nuget, nuget-package

I have a project that targets Windows Phone 7. I would like to use Json.NET in the project. But when I am trying to install the Json.NET package in my project via NuGet Package Manager it says:

> Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.1'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   'portable-win+net45+sl40+wp', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework.

I assume this is because latest version of Json.NET doesn't support Windows Phone 7. How can I install an older version of Json.NET? Preferably via NuGet. What is the latest Json.NET version compatible with Windows Phone 7?

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: simply download Json.net from codeplex , add reference and use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In given link all version of json .net command present you could try any of older version which would support in wp7...try one by one:

[NuGet Gallery | Json.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

Comment: Thanks for link, it led me to the answer; entering the following in the Package Manager Console: `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 5.0.8`

Comment: Just to update the issue: it was claimed that 6.0.3 is working with wp7, but in real it is not.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/02/01/json-net-6-0-release-1-%E2%80%93-jsonpath-and-f-support)
you can check it this version is not compatible with Windows phone 7.
"Change - .NET 4 Portable build targets WP8 and SL5 instead of WP7 and SL4"